# Can not Deserialize the Json C#

Tags: deserialization

I have following Json

"{\"Message\":\"The content you are deleting is associated with some other mashups.\",\"MashupList\":{\"70592\":\"low Frame Rated test\",\"70851\":\"low Frame Rated test\"}}"

I am unable to deserilize the MashupList part of this json. 70592 and 70851 are not the fixed attibutes they can be changed
what i have done so far

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomBaseAffectedMashupsResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "MashupList")]
    public MashupList MashupsList { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Message")]
    public String Message { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class MashupList 
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<String> MashupTitle { get; set; }
}
```

And the deserialize method

```
public static T Deserialise<T>(string json ) 
{   
        T obj =  default(T);
        try {
                obj =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                });

        return obj;
        } catch (Exception Exception)
        {
            return obj;
        }
}
```

it is not giving any error but i dont know why it does not deserilize MashupList part

I don't have enough reputation to comment so i am adding comment here it does not show any error but does not deserialize the

"MashupList\":{\"70592\":\"low Frame Rated test\",\"70851\":\"low Frame Rated test\"}

Comment: You're probably swallowing the error with the try/catch

Comment: Does it serialize the same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MashupList` property's type should be `Dictionary<string, string>`.

You don't need the `MashupList` class.

The keys are the numbers - `70592`, `70592`. The values are the strings, e.g. `low Frame Rated test`.

```
class CustomBaseAffectedMashupsResponse
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> MashupList { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```